# Why electric field due to a positive charge points radially outward?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conventions

We have always been taught and my book also says that electric field due to a positive charge points radially outwards.On the other hand for a negative charge the electric field  points radially inward.I could not understand the reason for this.Could someone give me a proper explanation?

Comment: What is your definition of (the direction of the) "electric field", and what trouble do you have in applying it here?

Comment: In most cases the difference between electrons and positrons is simply that their charges are the negative of each other. Presumably you could have electrons have their electric field lines pointing radially outwards, but to compensate you would have to introduce a load of negative signs in other definitions so you don't end up predicting (for instance) that other charged objects travel in the opposite direction in the presence of the electric field of an electron.

Answer (score 2):

The direction in which the field lines point between a pair of opposite charges is simply a matter of convention. The little arrows could be reversed throughout the universe and the physics would stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

How you measure the electric field? Take a unit test charge (positive conventionally) and then put it where you want to know the electric field and measure the force on a test charge at this point.

Now, Suppose you want to measure the electric field due to the positive charge, You put a testing charge and measure the force. We know that charges with the same sign repel each other, So the force on the test charge would be outward (along the line joining them). So the electric field due to positive charge would radially outward. Similar reasoning can be done for a negative charge.

---

Note that we do a measurement such that the test charge doesn't disturb the system itself. If the test charge chose to be negative the direction would be opposite, this is already pointed out by @niels in his answer.